# Java: Encoding of a mailto link with subject and plain text multiline body

Tags: java, email, utf-8, urlencode, mailto

I´ve googled a lot, but I wasn´t able to find a solution to my problem. I need to encode a mailto: link with subject and body to UTF-8 in java.

The body consists of plain text

*Is there any method which encodes:*

- the whole string in *UTF-8*, for example **Ä** to **%C3%84S**
- **blanks** into **%20** instead of **+**
- **\r\n** into **%0D%0A**
- **/** to **%2f**

*Thank you for your help!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [URLEncode.encode(String s, String enc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. The second parameter should be the string `UTF-8`.

It does encode spaces as `+` instead of `%20`, which is valid for query parameters; you can always just special-case that and replace all of the former with the latter. Example:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Foobar {
  private static Pattern space = Pattern.compile("\\+");
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String first = URLEncoder.encode("Ä+ \r\n/", "UTF-8");
    String second = space.matcher(first).replaceAll("%20");
    System.out.println(second);
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
%C3%84%2B%20%0D%0A%2F
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this already and it doesn´t encode **\r\n** right.

Comment: The carriage return and newline work fine for me. Updated with a regular expression to special-case using `%20` for spaces.